# Refresh ng-repeat list after adding item to PMA Database

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started learning AngularJS and now after I did all the tutorials I want to learn by myself by doing smaller projects like a Todo App or a small Blog System with posting, editing or deleting posts. I got to the point where I can create a new post. My problem now is that I don't want to refresh the entire page after someone added a new post, I want it to be shown on the page immediately after the person hit the Submit Button.

My Code so far:

maincontroller.js

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'postData', function($scope, postData) {
    $scope.getData = function() {
        postData.success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            $scope.posts = data;
            console.log("Posts are shown");
        }); 
    }
    $scope.getData();
}]);
```

formcontroller.js

```
app.controller('FormCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.refresh = function() {
        $scope.title = "";
        $scope.author = "";
        $scope.content = "";            
        console.log('Done refreshing');
    }

    $scope.submit = function() {
        console.log($scope.title);
        console.log($scope.author);
        console.log($scope.content);
        $http.post('php/insertdata.php', 
        {
            ftitle: $scope.title,
            fauthor: $scope.author,
            fcontent: $scope.content
        })
        .success(function(res){
            console.log(res);
            $scope.refresh();
        })
        .error(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    };
}]);
```

My Project is also on GitHub: https://github.com/MrSmooth/ng-blog

Don't judge my coding, I know it's not perfect. 
Thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: You will need a third party library like Pusher for the real time data binding with the server.

Comment: What is your res after you post to the server, is it a json representation of the object?

Comment: Exactly, its a json representation. I hoped to find a light way to refresh the post list without using a third party library, but if it is the only way possible...

Comment: if  'FormCtrl' is a child of 'MainCtrl' you could get hold of the $scope.posts array and update accordingly

Comment: Right now they are 2 seperate Controllers. I try and see if it works if FormCtrl would be a child of MainCtrl. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It worked just fine ! I just had to append the response from the success to my $scope.posts !